# Disable wake on fingerprint sensor

Tags: keyboard, fingerprint

I've spent a lot of time editing /system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl in trials to disable waking on sensor touch.
What I've learned is that MENU and SLEEP "buttons", when assigned to key 353 (which is my sensor) don't wake the device up, **BUT** they work as actual keys, which is unwanted.
So, what key should I assign to the sensor? 
I've tried avr, dvr, virtual, forward, media_close, meta_left, shift_left, escape, insert, button_l and a lot of other things. All of them wake the device, unfortunately.

P. S. Commenting or removing the line doesn't work either

Comment: On-device keys like MENU, VOL and POWER usually aren't defined in `Generic.kl` - try finding another `.kl` file which should only contain those definitions.

Comment: @AndyYan what do you mean? Usually? I described you HOW modifying Generic.kl affects sensor's behavior and you're telling me about other .kl files... FYI, none of other .kl files contain key 353, which makes me think they're not overriding generic one, at least not in my case